# Natural prosthetics

Tags: creature-design, brain

Many prosthetics work by receiving pressure from small movements and translating them into more complex movements.

[Ivan Davis](https://youtu.be/Lrpg820LuGE) for example has made himself a hand with full control of fingers which works by slightly moving or twisting parts of the wrist.

I want a creature eith the least amount of vital organs possible or atleast those organs to the smaller, but first I'm going to make this question specifically about the nervous system and spine.

The way I thought about reducing the spinal cord to the minimum was removing most flesh limbs and making them work like prosthetics but made from bone and tendons, possibly silicon bones since silicon is lighter.

They work just like Ivan's hand but in a more extreme way.
Small variations in the deep muscles of the chest and neck translate into complex movements of the limbs.

This way the animal is immune to being paralyzed, the only way to stop it is to shoot the head.

Does this mean that the limbs would be numb without tactile sensitivity or would it possible to have the pressure receptors work in the head?

Answer (score 4):

> This way the animal is immune to being paralyzed, the only way to stop it is to shoot the head.

Not really. If the main body needs some sort of connection to control the prosthetic, as soon as the connection is severed the prosthetic won't be controllable and for all meanings the main body will be "paralyzed".

Think of a man operating an excavator: cut down the controlling levers to operate the excavator, and the man, excavator-wise, will be the equivalent of being paralyzed in that he won't be able to control it.

That apart, if you want to have a sensory channel, you need to have a sensor on the limb and a transfer line bringing the signal from the sensor to the brain. If you cannot transform i.e. temperature in something that a muscle can feel (basically a force), you won't be able to perceive it.